# Where did I go wrong in my code for word count C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void wordCount(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream);

int main()
{
    char inputFile[100];
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    cout << "Enter a File name: " << endl;
    cin >> inputFile;

    fin.open(inputFile);
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    wordCount(fin, fout);
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}

void wordCount(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    int counter = 0,i;
    char next,last[1];
    in_stream.get(next);

    while (!in_stream.eof())
    {
        if (next == ' ')
            (next >> last[1]);

        for(i = 0; last[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        {   
            if (last[i] == ' ')
                counter++;
        }
        in_stream.get(next);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the word count of this and its not working
the chars being saved are fine, but whats not working if I input from notepad a file with something like:

I

am

working

it will show 0 words if I I type normally it will count the words why is that?

Comment: "_I cant use strings_" - Why? Please make your program compilable.

Comment: Where are you storing into `last[0]` through `last[4]`? BTW, `last[5]` is out of bounds.

Comment: I was storing it in the file I use to open with I believe? (I'm still super new at this)

Comment: I also added my full program

Comment: Sorry Ted, i was told by prof im not allowed. I'm not asking someone to solve this for me im just trying to understand why it will count characters in a straight text line but if i add \n it wont go to new line to count the words

Comment: I hate to say this but your code doesn't make much sense at all. Not sure what I'd suggest other than going back to the basics. You also have some glaring bugs that are unrelated to the logic of the program. For instance, if you declare an array of size 1, you cannot index at element 1. The only valid index is 0.

Comment: Alright I'll rewrite this (hopefully better), thanks for the input Fisher,  appreciate you taking time to look at this.

Answer (score 1):

I edit your code, Do you mean something like this?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int wordCount(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream);

int main()
{
    char inputFile[100];
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    cout << "Enter a File name: " << endl;
    cin >> inputFile;

    fin.open(inputFile);
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    int WordCount = wordCount(fin, fout);
    fin.close();
    fout.close();


    return 0;
}

int wordCount(ifstream& in_stream, ofstream& out_stream)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char data[100];

    in_stream >> data;
    while (strlen(data)>0)
    {
        counter++;
        in_stream >> data;
    }
    return counter;
}
```